# C#, IronPython - import(?) from a non-static class

Tags: c#, class, ironpython

I have a non-static C# class with some instance methods, which I need to call from IronPython scripts. Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
scope.SetVariable("class", instanceOfClass);
```

in C# code and

```
class.SomeMethod(args)
```

in script.

What I want is being able to call this class methods without adding `class.` each time in the script. Each script has its own instance of the class, and only one instance is used in one script.

If this class was static, the solution would be `from ClassName import *`, but as I know there is no similar construction for non-static classes.

How can this be done? I have some ideas (such as using reflection, or adding `class.` to each call in Python source programmatically), but they are overcomplicated and may be even not possible to implement.

UPD:

Problem solved by using such python code (before actual script):

```
def Method1(arg1): # for simple method
    class.Method1(arg1)

def Method2(arg = 123): # for default values
    class.Method2(arg)

def Method3(*args): # for params
    class.Method3(args)

# so on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from ClassName import *` is actually `from namespace import type`. This statement makes the type avaiable for use via the type name in Python. It makes no difference if the class is static or not. Consider this sample code - Environment being the static class.

```
import clr
from System import Environment
print Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

To solve your problem, inject a delegate to the class function into your ScriptScope, rather than the class itself.

Sample class

```
 public class Foo {
        public string GetMyString(string input) {
            return input;
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
 private static void Main(string[] args) {
            ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();

            string script = "x = GetMyString('value')";

            Foo foo = new Foo();

            ScriptSource scriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script);

            ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
            scope.SetVariable("GetMyString", new Func<string, string>(foo.GetMyString));

            scriptSource.Execute(scope);

            string output = scope.GetVariable<string>("x");
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

prints

> value

Comment: It works, of course, but the class has many methods, some of them with `params` arguments and default values, so it's not possible (i think) to create `Func<>`s and `Action<>`s for all of them.

Comment: And about imports - code like `from System.Console import *` and then `WriteLine(123)` works, so it imports not only types from namespaces, but also method from types.

Comment: You probably don't want to import the members of the type into the global scope, I don't believe that would provide an experience most Python users would be familiar with.

Comment: I had a play around with optional arguments and I believe you are going to have to create overloads in the C# class so the calls from Python will get directed to the correct member as the calls from the script are being invoked via the injected delegates so the signatures must match. You can wrap the params[] argument with your own delegate type though so that's a simple fix.

Comment: Why not import? Scripts are expected to be rather short, compared to normal python programs. Also, most of operations in the scripts are performed using this class (about which the question is), so it makes sense to import the methods into the global scope.

Comment: I tried working from IronPython with C# methods having optional and params arguments, and didn't notice any problems... So I can't see why to wrap them (and how)?

Comment: What is the actual reason for not wanting to use the "class" name? Is this a customization hook point? Optional and params arguments are supported directly but not if invoked via a delegate as the signature changes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7356/discussion-between-chersanya-and-michael-baker)